# Checking whether %APPDATA% exists always returns false

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I am trying to check whether my applications directory exists inside the %APPDATA% folder.

**My Problem:** Using `print os.path.exists("%APPDATA%")`, it always returns False which is obviously completely incorrect. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need expand environmental variables using [os.path.expandvars](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path#os.path.expandvars):

```
>>> os.path.expandvars("%APPDATA%")
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\falsetru\\Application Data'
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.expandvars("%APPDATA%"))
True
```

Without expanding, `"%APPDATA%"` means literally `%APPDATA%` in current working directory.

Comment: Oh, I thought the whole file path gets passed to windows (through Win32 API) and it expands it? Ie, Just call `FindFirstFileEx("%APPDATA%", ...);` and windows will expand the variable inside that function?

Comment: @JakeM: most Win32 API functions do not expand environment variables.

Comment: `os.path.exists` is implemented using `stat` which does not expand env var.